# Extracting UTM code from url into Google Form/Script javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Scenario: a UTM code is attached to a Google Form survey link that passes in a variable (eg lead source)

Goal: Extract that UTM code value from the link within the Google Form's script editor page and save it as a javascript variable.

My googling around teases that this is in theory possible, but I haven't found anything concrete. Does Team Overflow have any suggested ways to do this?

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Manager?

Comment: @sdhaus I have an account, but all I have "deployed" so far in that area is a simple link build with the UTM codes I want to use